# TypeError: Tensors in list passed to 'values' of 'Pack' Op have types [string, float32] that don't all match. error from CSV tutorial

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, tensorflow, tf.keras

I got my own data for training, etc in TensorFlow. I got the [Load CSV Data tutorial from TensorFlow on Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/docs/blob/master/site/en/tutorials/load_data/csv.ipynb), and I changed the config on some of the variables to match my data. When I ran the program, I got this error:

```
/tensorflow-2.0.0/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/autograph/impl/api.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    235       except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    236         if hasattr(e, 'ag_error_metadata'):
--> 237           raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    238         else:
    239           raise

TypeError: in converted code:

    <ipython-input-15-ed03747f8311>:2 pack  *
        return tf.stack(list(features.values()), axis=-1), label
    /tensorflow-2.0.0/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/util/dispatch.py:180 wrapper
        return target(*args, **kwargs)
    /tensorflow-2.0.0/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/ops/array_ops.py:1165 stack
        return gen_array_ops.pack(values, axis=axis, name=name)
    /tensorflow-2.0.0/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py:6304 pack
        "Pack", values=values, axis=axis, name=name)
    /tensorflow-2.0.0/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/framework/op_def_library.py:499 _apply_op_helper
        raise TypeError("%s that don't all match." % prefix)

    TypeError: Tensors in list passed to 'values' of 'Pack' Op have types [string, float32] that don't all match.
```

The whole output of the block is available [here on Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/X8YDGpdX).

The block ran in the tutorial is:

```py
packed_dataset = temp_dataset.map(pack)

for features, labels in packed_dataset.take(1):
  print(features.numpy())
  print()
  print(labels.numpy())
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem.

I accidentaly forgot that my 1st column was **not** numeric, so I removed it from the list.

```
# Before Stuff
After Stuff
```

```
# SELECT_COLUMNS = ['sid', 'dist', 'microtime']
SELECT_COLUMNS = ['dist', 'microtime']
# DEFAULTS       = ['a_r_d_b_id', 0.0, 0.0]
DEFAULTS       = [0.0, 0.0]
temp_dataset = get_dataset(train_file_path, 
                           select_columns=SELECT_COLUMNS,
                           column_defaults = DEFAULTS)

show_batch(temp_dataset)
```

```
example_batch, labels_batch = next(iter(temp_dataset))
```

```
def pack(features, label):
  return tf.stack(list(features.values()), axis=-1), label
```

```
packed_dataset = temp_dataset.map(pack)

for features, labels in packed_dataset.take(1):
  print(features.numpy())
  print()
  print(labels.numpy())
```